# Reverse proxy with Caddy Server / ApiPlatform (local SSL issues)

Tags: docker, api-platform.com, caddy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy, used to serve multiple ApiPlatform applications in local. My problem is that ApiPlatform 2.6 comes with Caddy Server, which set up HTTPS by default.

I cannot find a way for my reverse proxy to have the same self-signed certificate than the one used by ApiPlatform, always ending up with SSL errors...

Can you give me some advice ? Is there some resources to understand the mechanisms somewhere ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to
Use your own certificates and issue will be resolved

Check [Caddy Config](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls)  which let's you use your own certificate

```
tls [internal|<email>] | [<cert_file> <key_file>]
{
   protocols <min> [<max>] 
   ciphers <cipher_suites...>
   curves <curves...>
   alpn <values...> 
   load <paths...> 
   ca <ca_dir_url> 
   ca_root <pem_file>
   dns <provider_name> [<params...>] 
   eab <key_id> <mac_key> 
    on_demand   client_auth {       
        mode [request|require|verify_if_given|require_and_verify]   
        trusted_ca_cert <base64_der>    
        trusted_ca_cert_file <filename>     
        trusted_leaf_cert <base64_der>  
        trusted_leaf_cert_file <filename>
    }   
   issuer <issuer_name>
  [<params...>]
 }
```

As any reverse proxy or terminated proxy it provides means to let you specify certificates.